# Usage of prepositions in a sentence of/for

Tags: prepositions

1. Be prudential for your plan!
2. Be prudential of your plan!

Which sentence above is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You might say, "Be prudent with your plan!" but without more context, it is difficult for me to understand what the topic is that you are addressing. Here is another example in which I have made an assumption as to the topic: "Be prudent in planning for your future! Save a little money every month so you have something to live on when you are no longer able to work."